# VBS Script edit with line check

Tags: vbscript, edit

I am working on a script that edits an existing .ini file (nsapps.ini). Everything works well but I do not know how to add a check into the script that will make it stop adding the lines if the 3 lines are there

```
EpicTer78Class=9
EpicTer79Class=9
EpicTer81Class=9
```

The EpicTer78Class=9 is an existing line in the ini and the other 2 lines are supposed to be added after it. I want to add this check so if the script is accidently run more then once it wont add multiple coppies of the lines. Thank you for any help (I am a super noob when it comes to this).

```
 'Begin Code for script

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'Source file name here
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking10\nsapps.ini", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
'Line to find (changes go under this and replace line)
    intLineFinder = InStr(strNextLine, "EpicTer78Class=9")
    If intLineFinder <> 0 Then
    'This is what replaces first line (above)
        strNextLine = "EpicTer78Class=9" & vbCrLf & "EpicTer79Class=9" & vbCrLf & "EpicTer81Class=9"
    End If

    strNewFile = strNewFile & strNextLine & vbCrLf
Loop

objTextFile.Close
'Source of file goes here again
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking10\nsapps.ini", ForWriting)

objTextFile.WriteLine strNewFile
objTextFile.Close
```

Comment: I googled "vbscript add a line to ini file" and this came up first.  The funny thing is I am dealing with exactly the same compatibility fix for Epic+Dragon! Thanks for pioneering!

Comment: awesome! glad to be useful on this site for once. I work at Sparrow Health in the Ambulatory team but somehow ended up as the admin for this program as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the three lines are supposed to appear in the given order I'd suggest something like this:

```
inifile = "C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking10\nsapps.ini"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(inifile & ".new", 2, True)

prev = ""
Do Until inFile.ATEndOfStream
  curr = Trim(inFile.ReadLine)
  If prev = "EpicTer78Class=9" And curr <> "EpicTer79Class=9" Then
    outFile.WriteLine "EpicTer79Class=9"
    prev = "EpicTer79Class=9"
  End If
  If prev = "EpicTer79Class=9" And curr <> "EpicTer81Class=9" Then
    outFile.WriteLine "EpicTer81Class=9"
    prev = "EpicTer81Class=9"
  End If
  outFile.WriteLine curr
  prev = curr
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

fso.DeleteFile inifile, True
fso.MoveFile inifile & ".new", inifile
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works perfect. Looks a bit more complicated then I expected but I can see how it works I think....

Is it checking the previous line to match on it, then if matching writing the next line? If the last line (the 81 line) matches it signals that its done? 

thank you again and for helping me understand a little bit more.